# How to use namespace - Microsoft.Phone.Info - in native C++ on in WP 8.1 or WP 8

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working in a native C++ enviroment on WP8.1.

Let's say I want to call a functions like

```
Microsoft.Phone.Info::DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue( "DeviceUniqueId" );
```

The problem is no matter how I try, it didn't pass compile.

I know "Microsoft.Phone.Info" is a name space,

in C# ppl wrote:

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Info;
```

but in C++, I tried

```
using namespace Microsoft.Phone.Info;

void func()
{
    DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId");
}
```

didn't pass compile. or

```
void func()
{
    Microsoft.Phone.Info::DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId");
}
```

didn't pass compile.

It keeps telling me something like this

```
'Microsoft' : illegal use of namespace identifier in expression
```

so how do I use this namespace properly?

Thank you guys for the reading and answering. :-)
I can't find a C++ example for retriving the device ID. :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although many of the properties from `DeviceInformation` can be found on `EasClientDeviceInformation`, the device ID is not one of them. Instead, you should look at using the [ASHWID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification.getpackagespecifictoken.aspx) which will get you an app-specific hardware ID.

Answer (score 0):

In native WP runtime, using a namespace follows this syntax

```
 using namespace Windows::Phone::Info;
```

But you will find out that the namespace does not exist in runtime.  Only in WP Silverlight.

So you can look at this MSDN webpage that tells you where they moved all the functionality from 8.0 SL to 8.1 runtime.

[Windows Phone Silverlight to Windows Runtime namespace and class mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn800286.aspx)

Then if you search for "Windows.Phone.Info"  it will lead you to the new functions you should call.

Here is the ID : [EasClientDeviceInformation class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I got it:

```
EasClientDeviceInformation^ deviceInfo = ref new EasClientDeviceInformation();
deviceInfo->Id; //<- is what I want
```

Comment: The `Id` property is not supported on Windows Phone.

Comment: I see, it passed at the compile, failed at the runtime.